# Unable to flash Genymotion device with Gapps zip file, saves to SD card instead

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I am trying to flash my Samsung s5 emulator with the Gapps 4.4.4. file, however it saves to the sdcard instead. The file is a zip archive, and is not automatically opened by my browser. I have been able to flash the ARM-translator zip, which worked fine. I also have rebooted the device after each step. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all gapps are suitable for Genymotion 
So please try this and post result
https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145

Comment: I had tried this site previously, and it didn't work. Tried it out again tonight and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After install genymotion version 2.7.2, I think you must reboot computer to flash google apps